# scanf doesn't accept input

Tags: c

Only my first line of input request user to key in the value. Input B not request user to key in and shows wrong total.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 //BASIC CALCULATION INPUT 2 INTEGER ONE BY ONE
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a,b,c;
    //REQUEST ONE INPUT
    printf("Integer A: \n");
    scanf("%a",&a);
    //REQUEST ONE INPUT
    printf("Integer B: \n");
    scanf("%b",&b);

    c=a+b;
    //DISPLAY AMOUNT INTEGER
    printf("Total: &c",c);

    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your both scanf statements are wrong!
It should be
    scanf ("%d",&a);
    scanf ("%d",&b);
For taking user input a and b of type integer use %d.
&a is the reference (address) of identifer a which holds the value of a.
And also user output printf statement for integer c should be
    printf("%d",c);

Answer (score 0):

Add a space in the `scanf` to discard all **whitespace** before matching an integer. Such as a

```
scanf(" %b",&b); 
      ^^^
      space in the scanf
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of your scanf statements use wrong format specifiers. Thus [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

```
scanf("%a",&a);
```

and

```
scanf("%b",&b);
```

`a` expects a float*`as its argument, but you are passing`int*`. There's no format specifier`b` in standard C either.

Use `%d` to scan int's.

Better yet, [avoid `scanf` altogether](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) and use `fgets` and parse the line instead.

Another problem is your printf statement:

```
printf("Total: &c",c);
```

is wrong too. It should be:

```
printf("Total: %c",c);
```

to print the value of `c`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no format specifier like %b that's why Input B doesn't request user to key in.I think this this will help you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 //BASIC CALCULATION INPUT 2 INTEGER ONE BY ONE
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int a,b,c;
//REQUEST ONE INPUT
printf("Integer A: \n");
scanf("%d",&a);
//REQUEST ONE INPUT
printf("Integer B: \n");
scanf("%d",&b);

c=a+b;
//DISPLAY AMOUNT INTEGER
printf("Total: &c",c);

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```